# Logics for store letter in correct place

Tags: javascript

** I need new logics to store guessed letters in correct place. A game called hangman. As it is now the previous correct letter is overwritten if a new correct guess applys....**

```
function guessLetter() { 

var letter; 
var i;

var letterFound;
var correctLettersCount;
correctLettersCount=0;
letterBoxes = ""; 
letter = this.value;
for (i = 0; i < selectedWord.length; i++) {


    if (selectedWord.charAt(i) == letter) {   //if
        letterBoxes += "<span>" + letter + "</span >"; 


        } 
    else{   
        letterBoxes += "<span>*</span>"; 

    }
   document.getElementById("letterBoxes").innerHTML = letterBoxes; 

   }

}
```

Comment: Could you create a snippet that reproduce your error ?

Comment: Use an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). (Or perhaps an object.)

Comment: When asking on this site, go through these three steps: what it does, what it should do, and what you've tried so far. People are more likely to answer correctly if they know what the real question is. Saying "I need ___" with a piece of code is generally frowned upon.

Comment: http://www.dev.testingmb.se/

Comment: Code above is adding a new letter to the array, but gets overwritten for every new guess. For every correct guess it is supposed to show every correct letter.

Comment: @MattiasBengtsson Please create a snipper here. Don't show image. It won't help

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array that will store the `*` and letters found

In the following snippet, this array is called `display`

```js
const wordToFind = "testing";
const wordDisplay = document.getElementById("word");

let display = Array.from('*'.repeat(wordToFind.length));
wordDisplay.innerHTML = display.join("");


function checkLetter(el){
  const letter = el.value.toLowerCase();
  for(let i=0,l=wordToFind.length;i<l;i++){
    if(wordToFind[i]===letter)
      display[i] = letter;
  }
  el.value = "";
  wordDisplay.innerHTML = display.join("");
}
```

```html
<input oninput="checkLetter(this)" />
<p id="word"></p>
```